# Choosing a battery for my motor/controller

Tags: electric-bike, battery, motor

I'll keep this concise. While I'm pretty overwhelmed with all the reading I've been doing, I believe I'm close to making a decision and need a sanity check on the following:

- I purchased a [Bafang BBS02 from Luna Cycle](https://lunacycle.com/bafang-bbs02-750w-middrive-kit/).
- The key specs I noted are the it is compatible with 48v and 52v
  batteries and has a 25A controller, so I believe I need a battery
  that can supply 25A or greater.
- Luna is sold out of batteries, so I've narrowed my choices down to
  one of em3ev's batteries.
- I first looked at their [14S4P Super Shark](https://em3ev.com/shop/52v-14s4p-shark/) 35E option (Samsung
  Cells), but the recommended max discharge current is ~20A Continuous,
  27A Max Burst current. Because the continuous discharge current is
  less than the controller, I presume this is not a good choice.
- I then looked at their [14S5P Jumbo Shark](https://em3ev.com/shop/em3ev-52v-14s5p-jumbo-shark-ebike-battery/) in the 35E option
  (Samsung cells) has a recommended max discharge current of ~25A
  continuous, 34A Max Burst current. Since the controller will not draw
  more than 25A, then this strikes me as the perfect option. Are there
  any concerns with selecting this battery? Am I thinking about this correctly?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but shouldn't a 25A controller be able to deal with anything lower than that?  I mean the voltage is fixed, so as you vary the power applied you're changing the amount of current sent to the motor, so mostly the current will be below 25A anyway.  If you user a lower amperage battery you'll reduce your max power, but it shouldn't cause a problem with your controller.

Comment: The way I understand it, the amperage on the controller dictates the maximum it will ever draw from the battery, so you would generally want to avoid a battery that is not rated for a draw less than the controller amperage (not to say you will always draw what the controller is rated for). Rather, a battery that can handle draw higher than the controller draw is fine because its only going to supply whatever the controller draws.

Comment: Bafang Controllers are highly configurable by the end user and you can tune it in however you like, but since OP paid a premium for a "hot rodded" controller with upgraded power FETs, would probably be silly to then go into the software and back it off :)

Comment: I'd suggest the 25A continuous, although you won't need that very often. But your battery cells will last longer if you use them hard a lot. Just a side note: you may want to order the programming cable together with the motor.